# How to configure putty key bindings to work with cmd.exe correctly?

Tags: command-line, putty, keyboard-navigation

If putty is connected to a ssh server running on windows and cmd.exe is used as shell, the cursor keys do not work correctly. Typically you could recall old commands with `cursor up/down` but inside putty this does not work any more.

Changing the terminal type for putty did not work for me. Using an alternative shell would be no solution. If it is not possible with putty perhaps there is any alternative ssh client which allows modifications to the key-bindings/terminal emulation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem most likely is not the client, but the server.

PuTTY is an Xterm/VT100 terminal emulator. The VT100 terminal would be attached to one end of a simple 8-bit serial stream, and it would send special "escape sequences" for function keys – for example, `ESC [ A` for the <kbd>Up</kbd> arrow – and this has persisted in today's Linux and BSD. Line editing beyond basic <kbd>← Backspace</kbd> is handled by programs themselves, by reading and parsing these escape sequences, and outputting more of them in order to move the cursor and display text. Both Telnet and SSH can be thought of as simple carriers for the terminal stream, exactly like a serial line.

What causes your problems is that Windows consoles do *not* work that way – instead of being a stream, the console is a screen buffer. The console subsystem has line editing (and basic history) built in, and *cmd.exe* simply uses this functionality with *ReadConsole()* – arrow key events do not reach the program unless it specifically disables "line input" mode. (Windows API has separate functions for output styling as well.) When *cmd.exe*'s input is attached to a pipe, instead of a console, this system is bypassed and everything is inserted directly into the input stream. Since *cmd.exe* wasn't written to deal with VT100 sequences, it does not give any special treatment to them, and `ESC` simply becomes part of the entered command.

This means that Windows SSH servers, as well as the Windows built-in Telnet server, have to translate VT100 sequences to console events, and formatted console output to VT100 sequences. Not all SSH servers actually bother to do it. Make sure the remote end has not changed the SSH server software it users. If the keys *used to work* with the **same** configuration as now, do try resetting PuTTY to its default settings with `putty -cleanup` or by deleting the registry branch manually.

Windows PowerShell comes with [*remoting* support](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315349.aspx), which uses local line-editing and only sends complete lines to the remote end, avoiding this problem. For *cmd.exe*, this can be achieved with [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) (although the SMB connection is not encrypted by default), *or* you could probably start *cmd* from within a PowerShell remote session.

Comment: I tried cygwins sshd and freesshd which showed both the same behaviour. I also replaced cmd.exe with tcc.exe (Take Command Console) which still provides ANSI colour coding with escape sequences - and these colour coding is displayed properly.

Comment: @V15I0N Cygwin's ssh server is the same as you find on your usual Linux box, namely openssh. It doesn't contain special support for native console programs and is intended primarily for running a Cygwin shell, e.g. bash.

Comment: I have used Bitvise WinSSHd once. It worked rather nicely with cmd.exe.